# Length of 2D array[i]

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working in C, and am attempting to replicate the `length` member function that other languages (ie: C++) use to determine the length of an array or possibly vector of data. Is this something I can accomplish in C, or do I have to fall back onto examples like this:

```
int arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, in C, you use arrays as they are: a contiguous set of multiple pieces of data of the same type. You are generally expected to keep track of array sizes, along with the size of individual members, yourself.

In C++, for example, you have access to the Vector class, which encapsulates and handles all this record keeping for you.

In C, you would be expected to know exactly how big the array is. This is especially important in the case of pointer decay. Your initial example...

```
int arrayOfInts[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int sizeOfArray = sizeof(arrayOfInts) / sizeof(int); // Success; Returns "6"
```

This works in this case, but it will fail if you were to pass the array to a function expecting an array of integers (as a pointer) as a function argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int getArraySize(int* arr);

int main(void) {
   int arrayOfInts[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
   int sizeOfArray = getArraySize(arrayOfInts);
   return 0;
}

int getArraySize(int* arr) {
   int ret;
   ret = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int); // FAILS, returns the size of a pointer-to-int, not the size of the array
   return ret;
}
```

There are two ways to handle this: static definitions, or careful dynamic memory management.

```
// CASE 1: Trivial case, all arrays are of a static fixed size
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARR_SIZE (6)

int getArraySize(int* arr);

int main(void) {
   int arrayOfInts[ARR_SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
   int sizeOfArray = getArraySize(arrayOfInts);
   return 0;
}

int getArraySize(int* arr) {
   return ret ARR_SIZE;
}


// CASE 2: Managing sizes with dynamic allocation
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARR_SIZE (6)

int main(void) {
   int sizeOfArray = ARR_SIZE;
   int* arrayOfInts = malloc(sizeOfArray*sizeof(int));
   if (arrayOfInts != NULL) {
      // Success; initialize
      int i;
      for (i=0; i<sizeOfArray; i++) {
         arrayOfInts[i] = i;
      }
      return 0;
   } else {
      // Failed; abort
      sizeOfArray = 0;
      return (-1);
   }
}
```